# Sequelize cast in MAX causes TypeError: smth.col.startsWith

Tags: mysql, node.js, casting, sequelize.js

I use sequelize 5, mysql2 in a node 10 and having mysql as dialect

The logic is that I want to get a max `datetime` from a table, but get it only as date, not the time part, so obviously I will cast the attribute to `DATEONLY`

My query is

```
  Events.max(Sequelize.cast(Sequelize.col('eventTime'), 'DATEONLY'))
  .then((result)=>{   
    console.log('eventTime ', result);
    resolved(result.results);
  })
```

and I get the error :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: smth.col.startsWith is
>   not a function

If I remove the `cast` part and the query is like so

```
  Events.max('eventTime')
  .then((result)=>{   
    console.log('eventTime ', result);
    resolved(result.results);
  })
```

then this works fine.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Model.max first parameter is column name and not a sequelize function

Comment: Ok, but how I will get the data as a `DATEONLY` type? Thanks

Comment: Try to indicate `dataType: 'DATEONLY'` in options